# How to merge to different object lists by key C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've got two classes that I would like to merge/map by the Name property in each of them

```
public class Parameter
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RuleSetParameter
{
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterValue { get; set; }
    public int ParameterType { get; set; }
 }
```

I would like to merge these two lists, by joining them on the Name <-> ParameterName props, so that I can get the ParameterValue.

This is what I have thus far:

```
var parameterDictionary = RuleSetParameter.Zip(parameters).ToDictionary(x => x.First, x => x.Second);
```

I know this won't work, because this will just map them in the order received.

Any guidance on how to achieve the desired result?

Comment: If you are open to 3rd party libraries, there's a great library for this called AutoMapper, and you can leverage it to specify mappings from a source object to a destination object

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted or clarify your question if the answers given don't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this resolved using the Join method:

```
 var result = fieldMap.RuleSetParameter.Join(parameters, arg => arg.ParameterName, arg => arg.Name,
                (first, second) => new { first.ParameterName, ParameterValue = second.Value, first.ParameterType });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define an interface

```
public interface IParameter
{
   string Name { get; set; }
   string Value { get; set; }
}

public class Parameter : IParameter
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class RuleSetParameter : IParameter
{
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }
    public string ParameterValue { get; set; }
    public int ParameterType { get; set; }

    //explicit interface implementation 
    string IParameter.Name 
    { 
        get => this.ParameterName;
        set => this.ParameterName = value;
    }
    string IParameter.Value
    { 
        get => this.ParameterValue;
        set => this.ParameterValue = value;
    }
}
```

Now you can easily define a `IDictionary<string, IParameter>`

```
var parameters = new List<Parameter>()
{
    new() { Name = "P1", Value = "V1" },
    new() { Name = "P2", Value = "V2" },
};

var resultSetParameters = new List<RuleSetParameter>()
{
    new() { ParameterName = "RP1", ParameterValue = "RV1" },
    new() { ParameterName = "RP2", ParameterValue = "RV2" },
};

var dictParametrs = parameters.Cast<IParameter>().Concat(resultSetParameters).ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
```

Here a demo:

[sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)